# How to select vertices on an edge-to-face intersection?

Tags: select

Good day! Soo, my problem is I want to create a face in the following area (screenshots attached). But I can't select the corners which is quite obvious. But anyway how to do it? Thanks.[image]

Comment: It might be more helpful is you also included a screen-shot where you put the object in edit mode, vertex select mode, press 'a' (all) so one could see if there is one vertex in each of the corner points, or many along the way of the top outer edges.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is are only four vertices in the top quad, and assuming that they all have one location axis being identical (example co.z are all the same)... In EDIT mode select those four vertices and then press 'f' or menu :: Vertex :: New edges/face from vertices.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think I solved this issue by using Boolean modifier to "project" the vertical cube to create vertices on the same plane as the area I wanted to select.